# Symfony 3 security After login there is an infinite redirect

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security

I have a problem with custom symfony security login inspired by tutorial "How to Build a Traditional Login Form" from Symfony cookbook. Everything works fine until I log in from /login route. Then every route I want redirect to is causing an Infinite loop. Maybe I'm missing something?

//security.yml
    security:

```
encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

providers:
    mysql:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:User
            property: username


firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
        logout:
            path: logout


access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

//routing.yml

```
index:
path: /
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Main:main }
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

//SecurityController.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction() {
    $authenticationUtils = $this->get("security.authentication_utils");

    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    $name = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render(
        ':security:login.html.twig',
        ["name" => $name, "error" => $error]
    );
}
/**
 * @Route("/login_check", name="login_check")
 */
public function loginCheckAction() {
}
/**
 * @Route("/logout",name="logout")
 */
public function logoutAction() {
}

}
```

//login.twig.html

```
{% if error %}
<div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
     <label for="username">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ name }}" />

     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
     <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/" />

     <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay so I finally located problem and the problem wasnt in the routes or security at all. I just did serializing in User Entity wrong. Some misspell symfony doesnt mentioned in debugger. It is weird it caused this kind of behaviour. Anyway thanks to anyone who tried to help me.

Comment: I thank you very much, the same thing happened to me and I had about 5 hours in this

Comment: Live saviour! After 2 days, this was the right point. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
access_control:
- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

to

```
access_control:
- { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

to have login_check behind the firewall.

Your routing.yml seems odd to me, could you post your controller and your twig to see your routes ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the login script is forwarding you to the login page, when it sees that you are logged in it's forwarding you to the referrer.. which is the login page.. and so on..

To get around this you have a few options.

1) You could set a default target path in your `app/config/security.yml` so that every time a user logs in they are forwarded to the specific route. The issue with this approach is that the use of `always_use_default_target_path` will mean that it will never go to the referring page but if you don't use it and you fail an attempt at logging in it will direct you to the login page (the referrer at this point).

```
firewalls:
    //..
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            default_target_path: **default_route**
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
        logout:
            path: logout
```

2) You could set a field in your form login that sets a default target path, which could be the referrer or a specified one depending on the case. This issue with this approach is that the user will need to go through the login process to be forwarded so if the users goes back to the login page for some reason they will be required to login again before being redirected.

```
//...

{% set referer = app.request.headers.get('referer') %}
{% set targetPath = referer is not null and referer != url('login')
    ? referer
    : path('**default_route**')
%}

<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
    //...

    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ targetPath }}" />
</form>
```

3) **My recommendation** You could set a check in your login controller that can check if the user is already logged in and then redirecting the user to a specific route. The benefit of this is that it will stop users that are already logged in going to the login form but will still enable you to forward user to the referring page/route when possible.

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction() {
    if (null !== $this->getUser()) {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('**default_route**'));
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Still nothing. I tried every recomendation with no improvements.

Answer (score 0):

@qooplmao I don't understand why you said "the referrer.. which is the login page" the referrer is "/" witch is not the login page ("/login") but a route somewhere in the mainController.
If the /login route match before / it will be ok no ?

Earlier Routes always Win then the routing.yml could be

```
login:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php"
    type:     annotation
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
index:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Main:main }
```

You could remove the index too if you use annotations in the main controller.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. index is used like some kind of hotfix to set default route. AppBundle:Main:main annotation is defined as /page/{slug} with default value for slug

Comment: What say the debug toolbar ?

Comment: Just to understand You want your website entirely behind the firewall ?

Comment: Yes. The problem is there is not debug toolbar at all. It is just loading and nothing is send to browser.

Answer (score 0):

try like this :
security.yml security:

```
encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

providers:
    mysql:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:User
            property: username


firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
        logout:
            path: logout


access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

routing.yml

```
login:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php"
    type:     annotation
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

SecurityController.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction() {
    $authenticationUtils = $this->get("security.authentication_utils");

    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
    $name = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render(
        ':security:login.html.twig',
        ["name" => $name, "error" => $error]
    );
}
/**
 * @Route("/login_check", name="login_check")
 */
public function loginCheckAction() {
}
/**
 * @Route("/logout",name="logout")
 */
public function logoutAction() {
}

}
```

login.twig.html

```
{% if error %}
<div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
     <label for="username">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ name }}" />

     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
     <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ path('THE_NAME_OF_THE_ROUTE_YOU_WANT_TO_GO') }}" />

     <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

In your mainController need to use annotations routes and replace for example 'THE_NAME_OF_THE_ROUTE_YOU_WANT_TO_GO' by '/page'  if it's the route you want to go...

some help here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

Comment: Now, after I restart my laptop and log in I am redirected to **localhost:8000/page** but its a blank page and then same problem occurre again. Inifinite page loading on any request I try. even routes that doesnt exist are causing infinite page loading.

Comment: Could You try to remove the firewall and test your maincontoller with /page looks like there is a problem with your controller ...

Comment: Doesnt work. I removed the firewall and the problem persist. It's just strange because everything works just fine until I log in. Do you want to see MainController.php?